# Keep divs from overflowing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I keeps these two from overflowing? I have tried almost everything so i don't know where to go from here.
`div`s are marked with green and orange.
[image]

[image]

```css
#stemplingerclass {
    clear: both;
    max-width: 100%;

}

#datoid 
{

   clear: both;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10 text-center" style="background-color: green;" >
         <div id="datoid">


         </div>
      </div>

       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-10" style="background-color: orange;">
         <div id="stemplingerclass">

         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: have you tried `overflow-y: hidden;` ?
and btw your code-snippet doesent work...

Comment: update your code in fiddle

Comment: overflow-y: hidden; gives me the "same" result it just makes the calender part scrollable.

Comment: You can use `overflow: hidden;` to hide part of the element that exceeds the container area but that wouldn't be ideal. You need to update the style of the content itself (ie. calendar and form table) to be responsive first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: flex;` to container of these two divs.
If you want children not to stretch also add `align-items: flex-start;` to you container.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#greenpart{
  display: inline-block;
width:49%;
    overflow: scroll;
    }

    #orangepart{
        display: inline-block;

width:49%;
    overflow: scroll;

    }
```

```html
<div id="greenpart" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10 text-center" style="background-color: green;" >
             <div id="datoid">

    test1
             </div>
          </div>

           <div id="orangepart"class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-10" style="background-color: orange;">
             <div id="stemplingerclass">
    test2
             </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: Did not work, displayed the 2 columns underneath each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #datoid {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: inherit;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#stemplingerclass {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  float: right;
  background-color: inherit;
  overflow: scroll;
}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10 text-center" style="background-color: green;" >
             <div id="datoid">


             </div>
          </div>

           <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-10" style="background-color: orange;">
             <div id="stemplingerclass">

             </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```